# SenTestingKit in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sentestingkit

Hi I've got this caution message, I didn't have it before:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit (2 slices)
```

How can I fix it?

I tried with the "${DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR}/Frameworks" in the Framework Search Path but nothing happens.

Thanks in advance